# What TUI did Ubuntu 18.04 Server installer use?

Tags: user-interface, ubuntu

Just tried to install Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Server, and found its TUI quite neat. What TUI lib did the installer use to display its UI?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The new Ubuntu Server installer (since 18.04) is [Subiquity](https://github.com/CanonicalLtd/subiquity) ("[Ubiquity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubiquity_(software)) for servers"). It uses the [`urwid`](http://urwid.org/) Python library for its interface.